# d3 animating multiple lines the line can't be completed

Tags: animation, d3.js, transition

I want to do an animation on the lines, but the second line will draw from two parts, one from begining, and the other from close to the second last point and disappear, so I got a result like this
[image]

I was following others'code

```
 const pathLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
      const transitionPath = d3.transition().ease(d3.easeQuad).duration(3000);
      path
        .attrs({
          "stroke-dashoffset": pathLength,
          "stroke-dasharray": pathLength,
        })
        .transition(transitionPath)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

if you need all the code, I can paste, but it is really just this part that works with the animation, thank you!

Comment: I figure out by "stroke-dashoffset": pathLength * 1.5,
          "stroke-dasharray": pathLength * 1.5, more explanation is welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I think you're accidentally using the same path length twice - namely that of the first path. `path.node()` returns the first node, even if there are multiple nodes in the selection.

```js
const data = [{
  category: "series_1",
  values: [{
      name: "A",
      value: 10
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      value: 21
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      value: 19
    },
    {
      name: "D",
      value: 23
    },
    {
      name: "E",
      value: 20
    },
  ],
}, ];
let counter = 1;
const add_set = (arr) => {
  let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr[0]));
  const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
  const add = (arr) => {
    counter++;
    copy.values.map((i) => (i.value = random()));
    copy.category = `series_${counter}`;
    arr.push(copy);
  };
  add(arr);
};
add_set(data);

//No.1 define the svg
let graphWidth = 600,
  graphHeight = 300;
let margin = {
  top: 60,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 45
};
let totalWidth = graphWidth + margin.left + margin.right,
  totalHeight = graphHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom;
let svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", totalWidth)
  .attr("height", totalHeight);
//No.2 define mainGraph
let mainGraph = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//No.3 define axises
let categoriesNames = data[0].values.map((d) => d.name);
let xScale = d3
  .scalePoint()
  .domain(categoriesNames)
  .range([0, graphWidth]); // scalepoint make the axis starts with value compared with scaleBand
let colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
colorScale.domain(data.map((d) => d.category));

let yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([graphHeight, 0])
  .domain([
    d3.min(data, (i) => d3.min(i.values, (x) => x.value)),
    d3.max(data, (i) => d3.max(i.values, (x) => x.value)),
  ]); //* If an arrow function is simply returning a single line of code, you can omit the statement brackets and the return keyword

//No.4 set axises
mainGraph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + graphHeight + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
mainGraph.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
//No.5 make lines
let lineGenerator = d3
  .line()
  .x((d) => xScale(d.name))
  .y((d) => yScale(d.value))
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var lines = mainGraph
  .selectAll(".path")
  .data(data.map((i) => i.values))
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colorScale(i));

//No.6 append circles
let circleData = data.map((i) => i.values);
mainGraph
  .selectAll(".circle-container")
  .data(circleData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circle-container")
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => console.log(d) || colorScale(i))
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data((d) => d)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attrs({
    cx: (d) => xScale(d.name),
    cy: (d) => yScale(d.value),
    r: 3,
    opacity: 1,
  });

// HERE we let the lines grow
lines
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", function(d) {
    // Get the path length of the current element
    const pathLength = this.getTotalLength();
    return `0 ${pathLength}`
  })
  .transition()
  .duration(2500)
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", function(d) {
    // Get the path length of the current element
    const pathLength = this.getTotalLength();
    return `${pathLength} ${pathLength}`
  });
```

```css
.line {
  stroke: blue;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```